# Flickering OccupancyGrid data in RViz2

Tags: rviz, python, mapping, rclpy

I'm implementing my own custom message of type nav_msgs/msg/OccupancyGrid to visualize grid-based quantities in a local map (namely virtual pheromones).

Back in ROS Noetic, my implementation worked very smoothly in RViz. Now that the QoS policy has replaced some TCP-based topic logic, I had to make some changes to be able to view my map. Before you redirect me to other links regarding QoS, I have made sure myself to read the recent proposal [REP 2003](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-rep-2003-sensor-data-and-map-qos-settings/35758), the [REP 2003 page](https://ros.org/reps/rep-2003.html) and this [RQt issue](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt/issues/187).

I can currently see the map in RViz, even though it has a flickering problem with some delays. I've made sure to call QoSProfile in my map publisher, as below, per Steve Macenski's TL;DR instructions:

```py
from rclpy.qos import QoSProfile, DurabilityPolicy, HistoryPolicy, ReliabilityPolicy
from nav_msgs.msg import OccupancyGrid
...
qos_policy = QoSProfile(reliability= ReliabilityPolicy.RELIABLE,
      history= HistoryPolicy.KEEP_LAST,
      durability= DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL,
      depth= 3)
pheromone_grid_pub = self.create_publisher(
        topic="/pheromone/grid",
        msg_type= OccupancyGrid,
        qos_profile= qos_policy)
```

[image: Pheromone grid data]

The problem is mitigated with these settings, but not completely solved. There is still some delaying, and major flickering issues persist.

[image]

What would be the best course of action in this case to improve RViz2 performance? Do I need to raise the topic depth? There also is a new "update topic" field that doesn't make a lot of sense to me, and I couldn't find any documentation related to it. Or, is there a better alternative message type altogether to publish this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like - to my eye - one of two things:

1. You have two publishers publishing to the same topic containing different data. So the most recent one is being shown and you're seeing the race condition of which was published last
2. In your software, you have a bug resulting in the publication of two different states.

If you stop your nodes, does it stop flickering? Then its your nodes :-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and insightful response.
I'm taking a look at your recommendations.
1. This seems to be impossible, given that there only is one node tasked with RViz visualizations. That node takes in the pheromone grid topic, and produces a map that is useful for RViz. There is also one node that is tasked with modifying the pheromone grid. That node takes a multitude of requests (which is basically, you should place pheromones near this robot right now) - but the pheromone grid data virtually has no problems. The robots interact with the pheromone grid with no issues.

Comment: Another detail is that the "flicker" occurs over what should be the actual grid image on the screen. Most of the time I do see the correct data, but some data from the past keeps on blinking over it. 
2. Stopping the RViz visualizer node absolutely does not stop the blinking. I should also repeat that this is the only node that provides the map information. Also the fact that the node was only modified to work with ROS 2 remains, in ROS 1 the same node produces no issues. I will check the changes to pinpoint what exactly is different.

Comment: Some of the background flickering was ironically due to a visualizer node not shutting down properly. Fixing that, I am only left with data from only now, but it still flickers. The longer it works, the worse the flickering gets. The duplicate node only seems to have made this process faster. Increasing QoS depth and halving the publish frequency did improve performance a bit. Do you have any further ideas regarding tuning these settings?

Comment: I still think your nodes are probably broken and this doesn't have anything to do with QoS

Comment: Alright, thank you for your time. At least having a good opinion about my QoS settings will help in narrowing down the problem.